# jquery href and click event sync

Tags: jquery, click, location, href, delay

Guys I have a problem with synchronization betwen two actions.
At first link:

```
<a href="#mytag1">Link 1</a>
<a href="#mytag2">Link 2</a>
<a href="#mytag3">Link 3</a>
```

And the JQuery event binding:

```
$('a').click(function(){recognize_content_by_link()});
```

This function gets using other function (let it be geturl()) window.location.href, parse it to get '#mytagX' from it and load content.

The problem is: I need to set href at first, and then get url from window.location to parse it in binded function. I had heen trying to delay it by setTimenterval on geturl() function used inside recognize_content_by_link() befere post here, but it is poor solution. 
Any ideas? Need it really rapidly - exam time :( Big thanks for any help!

(sorry for my language)

Comment: show the other code... really not clear what issue is

Answer (score 1):

Queue it after the event by using a timeout with delay `0`.

```
$('a').click(function() {
  setTimeout(function() {
    recognize_content_by_link();
  }, 0);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need this:

```
$('a').click(function(e){
   e.preventDefault();
   recognize_content_by_link();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with a named function :

```
$('a').click(recognize_content_by_link);

function recognize_content_by_link(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var hash = this.hash.replace(/^[#]/, '');
    ....
}
```

or an anonymous function :

```
$('a').click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var hash = this.hash.replace(/^[#]/, '');
    ....
});
```